# Building e-mail server

Tags: java, email

I have a project with a use case where users should be able to send private messages to other users but this should be integrated with their e-mail box. They should be able to send either private messages or e-mail messages from the same screen.

My thought is to use some kind of open-source e-mail server which will dump the e-mails into MongoDB and then have my Java API pull them out and display them on the interface. And when a user sends an e-mail it is passed by the API to the e-mail server.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: How are the private messages different from any other email message?

Comment: They are not necessarily sent to people with e-mail accounts e.g. they might be sent to people just members of the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your own server (not unreasonable in many cases), check out [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) - an open-source Java mail server with a plug-in capability. Obviously (!) you can use JavaMail to talk to this, pull messages back etc.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Gmail do all of this already? If you want email with chat integration,* that's the first solution that comes to mind. Why reinvent the wheel?

---

*and about a bajillion other awesome features